# Rational exponents in terms of simple operations

Tags: roots, exponentiation

So I have to do a geometric average on a website that doesn't have the geometric average function.

Furthermore, it doesn't allow power or root operators, it only has multiplication, division, addition and subtraction.

How would I represent a $x^{\frac13}$ as ONLY `*,/,+,-`?

Is it even possible?

Comment: +1. I think this a good question.

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible, unless I’m not being clever enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to compute *exactly* $x^{1/2}$, $x^{1/3}$ or any other non-integral power of $x$ using only $+-×÷$ for general $x$. Suppose $x$ is rational, then any expression with $x$, decimal constants and the four operations remains rational, yet $x$ is usually irrational (think $\sqrt2$).

Thus numerical methods will be required to compute such powers to sufficient precision. There are many such methods available for $n$th roots, which is all that is required for the geometric mean. The "classic" approach (naming the number to take the $n$th root of as $A$) starts from some guess $x_0$ and iterates $x_{k+1}=x_k+\frac{Ax_k^{1-n}-x_k}n$.

Comment: In that case, is there any way to compute a geometric functions without appealing to exponents at all? Or actually by just using the square root x^(1/2) because it only has a sqrt function, but my function has 6 terms, so I would need x^(1/6)

Comment: @iamAguest No. Even if you had a square root, you would only be able to compute that, the fourth root, the eighth root, etc. by repeatedly taking square roots. It can be shown that you cannot generate $\sqrt[3]2$ by $+-×÷\sqrt$.